# LED Ceiling Spotlight Remote Color Changing Switch Installation

Tags: lighting, ceiling, led

I am fairly new to electrical DIY. I am planning to install 16 of these [dimmable spotlight fixtures](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0828J8KVL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) over two rooms with two switches:

As a reference, similar to these ones:
[Is a grommet needed for romex into this metal junction box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/177865/is-a-grommet-needed-for-romex-into-this-metal-junction-box/177910#177910)

They come with a color changing switch assembled to a small printed circuit inside the electrical box, have anyone have attempted to rewire this switch to an external position by the switch wall so that the color can be changed at any time and what parts can be used to do so?

Thank you very much,

Comment: I'm confused - I don't see anything about color changing in that product listing. You can purchase them in one of 3 color temps, but I'm not seeing anything about changing it once you've purchased. Sure the link is correct? Also, I'm not seeing the tie in to the other [diy.se] question you linked - that's about using a cable clamp on the box (which you should do when wiring these). Please [edit] your post to correct the links or to more carefully explain "color changing switch" statement.

Comment: Beware: more cheap Cheese junk.  It's not even Amazon selling it despite appearances.  This is the "Amazon Marketplace" flea market.   Anytime you see "Sold by XXX and Fulfilled by Amazon", it means you're dealing with the eBay/Alibaba crowd and the stuff is rubbish.  Their latest trick is to claim ETL listing, but when you get the item, not actually listed... it has to be CSA/UL/ETL listed to be used in CA.

Answer (score 0):

### It wouldn't be electrically possible without a legion of relays.

The problem is, the switch was only ever intended to be used at the time of installation.  You would have to open up every single -- how many of these are you installing? -- and throw the switch.  Might as well just keep the ladder in the living room at that point.

You could  come off the switches with 3-4 wires, and extend those out to another switch... but you would have to do that *per light*, so now instead of a ladder you only need a broomstick with an eyebolt screwed into the end.

Why not wire all the switches in parallel over to a light switch in the wall?  Because the power supplies are not designed to all be shorted to each other like that.

So the only way that works is to have 1-2 relays at each light location, with the relay contacts wired to emulate the switches.  Then, the relay coils could be paralleled and supplied from *yet another* independent power supply (though you might be able to tap your furnace's 24V 40VA transformer for this purpose).

### Reputable firms make this. It's expensive, but it isn't a support dead-end like this would be.

The sheer amount of labor and troubleshooting involved makes it a highly improbable venture. Further, it would be totally unsupportable except by the mad genius who built it, so would be a very serious problem at resale.   If you're *that intense* into home automation, go for it **except use reputable parts**.

But for anyone else, it seems like you'd be better off talking to the lighting shops that supply million dollar mansions ($10M mansions in NYC, SF, LA, Boston) and getting well-supported stuff from reputable vendors.